# How to plot solutions for simultaneous equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, variable

I have 2 simultaneous equation of $x$ and $y$.  Here is how I solve it, and it works.  But I want to vary the parameters `n` and `imax`, and plot the result of `seeb*(xx - yy)` vs `imax` for different values of `n` (say `imax` from 1 to 10 and `n=17,30,100,1000`).  How can I do that?  Thanks.

```
n = 17;  
imax = 0.5; 

seeb = 2*n*0.0002; 
dTmax = 300 - ((Sqrt[1 + 2*0.72] - 1)/(0.72/300));
vmax = seeb*300;
qmax = seebimax*300 - 0.5*imax*seeb*(300 - dTmax);
r = (300 - dTmax)*vmax/(300*imax); 
rth = (2*300*dTmax)/((300 - dTmax) vmax*imax); 
length = r/(0.001/100)*0.65*0.65/1000/2/n;


equation1[x_, y_] := -(308 - x)/0.01 + (x - y)/rth + 
  seeb^2*x*(x - y)/2/r - 0.5 seeb^2*(x - y)*(x - y)/4/r
equation2[x_, y_] := (y - 300)/100 - (x - y)/rth - 
  seeb^2*y*(x - y)/2/r - 0.5 seeb^2*(x - y)*(x - y)/4/r
{xx, yy} = {x, y} /. 
  FindRoot[{equation1[x, y], equation2[x, y]}, {{x, 308}, {y, 300}}]

Print["V="]; seeb*(xx - yy)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by wrapping your code by Table. Something like this:

```
Clear[imax];
n=17;

lst = Table[{imax, seeb = 2*n*0.0002;
   dTmax = 300 - ((Sqrt[1 + 2*0.72] - 1)/(0.72/300));
   vmax = seeb*300;

   r = (300 - dTmax)*vmax/(300*imax);
   rth = (2*300*dTmax)/((300 - dTmax) vmax*imax);
   length = r/(0.001/100)*0.65*0.65/1000/2/n;

   equation1[x_, y_] := -(308 - x)/0.01 + (x - y)/rth + 
     seeb^2*x*(x - y)/2/r - 0.5 seeb^2*(x - y)*(x - y)/4/r;
   equation2[x_, y_] := (y - 300)/100 - (x - y)/rth - 
     seeb^2*y*(x - y)/2/r - 0.5 seeb^2*(x - y)*(x - y)/4/r;
   fr = FindRoot[{equation1[x, y], 
      equation2[x, y]}, {{x, 308}, {y, 300}}];
   {xx, yy} = {x, y} /. fr}, {imax, 1, 10, 0.5}];
```

Then you get the list each element of which has the structure `{imax, {solution1, solution2}}`. It can be printed as follows:

```
ListPlot[{lst /. {x_, {y_, z_}} -> {x, y}, lst /. {x_, {y_, z_}} -> {x, z}}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]
```

yielding the plot:

[image]

Since you need to do all this with different n values you can wrap it by table once more:

```
Clear[n, imax]];

lst2=Table[thePreviousCodeWithoutnAssignment,{n,{17,30,100,1000}}]
```

However, your plot will be overcrowded in such a case.

Have fun!